# What is maximum size of S3 object in case of Cost and Usage report in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, cost-management

> The size of an individual report can grow to more than a gigabyte and
>   might exceed the capacity of desktop spreadsheet applications to
>   display every line. If a report is larger than most applications can
>   handle, AWS splits the report into multiple files that are stored in
>   the same folder in the Amazon S3 bucket.

The following statement is found in AWS docs for [Cost and Usage reports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-reports-costusage-files.html)

I tried to search on the maximum size , possible for this object but I was not able to spot it. Is there a possible reference for this?

Comment: The *"capacity of desktop spreadsheet applications to display every line"* likely limits the number of *rows* to <= 1,048,576, which is the row limit of the current generation of MS Excel-compatible tools.  The limit may be based on row counts, rather than sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum is 5 TB . In single PUT, Max is 5 gb.

Comment: 5 TB is the size of the bucket. This is a report generated on AWS side and cannot be read if its 5 TB. He has mentioned about this in the link but its clear as he has not given a cap on the size of the file. I need a reference or a convincing answer atleast on the max size expected for this report